# php doesn't add a div, it changes the page completely

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, contact-form

I am trying to make a contact form in PHP and HTML. The code works but the problem is that is completely changes the page simply ruining the process of having only a single change: the div that goes on the bottom of the form. Here is my php file:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $url = $_POST['url'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = 'Partner from Website';
        $to = 'jordanwhite916@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'VetConnexx Partner Inquiry';
        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message:\n $message";
        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }
        if (!$_POST['title']) {
            $errTitle = 'Please enter your title';
        }
        if (!$_POST['phone']) {
            $errPhone = 'Please enter your phone';
        }
        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }
        if (!$_POST['url'] || !filter_var($_POST['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            $errURL = 'Please enter a valid website';
        }
        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }
        //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
        if ($human !== 5) {
            $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
        }
// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman && !$errTitle && !$errPhone && !$errURL) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Become a VetConnexx Business Partner.</p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <p>VetConnexx brings the mission focused discipline, integrity, and motivation of the US Armed Forces
        to your customers. VetConnexx has been tested by the best and exceeds the standards expected of
        Fortune 100 companies and their privately held peers.</p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <p>We can bring the same level of service to your business. To discuss our client services, please
        contact us at <a href="mailto:VetPartners@VetConnexx.com">VetPartners@VetConnexx.com</a></p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="businesspartners.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']); ?>">
                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errTitle</p>";?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']); ?>">
                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errPhone</p>";?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="url" class="col-sm-2 control-label">URL</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="url" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" placeholder="www.examplewebsite.com" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['url']); ?>">
                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errURL</p>";?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="How may we help you?"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?></textarea>
                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer">
                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errHuman</p>";?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <?php echo $result; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form> 
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The link to the website I am trying to develop is located here: Go to Business Partners, and fill out the information in the contact form to see what may be wrong. I only want the div on the bottom to show after the Send button is click, not for a completely white page with black text and forms to come up that has the same content. Here's the link to the website:

http://www.sampsonvision.com/VetConnexxWebsite

Comment: Question is not clear. The link you shared looks like already working the way you described.

Comment: Is that code the only code in the file `businesspartners.php`? If yes, then that is why the page is white. You are not including your layout template anywhere. The form just submits to the page `businesspartners.php` and that file only renders that form.

Comment: Important to note the use of angular.js, required to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you want to use AJAX call to your PHP file instead of a simple submission. Because after form submission, the only content appears on a page is that one which was generated by the script. Your script outputs only one `div`.